# Android 7.0. setting AudioManager mode to vibrate

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

This question refers to Android APK 24 and above, cause it works for previous versions. Can set mode to `silent` like this:

```
am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

But, it doesn't work for `vibrate`:

```
am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

I've also tried to set them to fixed values(e.g. 0 and 1). I'd be grateful if anyone could point to changes in Android Nougat.